# Django + PostgreSQL group by date on datetimefield

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which has a datetimefield that I'm trying to annotate on grouping by date.

Eg:

```
order_totals = Transfer.objects.filter(created__range=[datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min) + datetime.timedelta(days=-5), datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.max)]).values('created').annotate(Count('id'))
```

The problem with the above is it groups by every second/millisecond of the datetime field rather then just the date.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by using QuerySet.extra and add a column to the query

eg.

```
qs.filter(...).extra(select={'created_date': 'created::date'}).values('created_date')
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting on [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#query-expressions-conditional-expressions-and-database-functions), you can also use the new [DateTime expression](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/db/models/expressions.py#L857) (weirdly it's is not documented in the [built-in expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#built-in-expressions) sheet).

```
import pytz
from django.db.models.expressions import DateTime

qs.annotate(created_date=DateTime('created', 'day', pytz.UTC))
```

If you want to group by `created_date`, just chain another aggregating expression :

```
qs.annotate(created_date=DateTime('created', 'day', pytz.UTC)).values('created_date').annotate(number=Count('id'))
```

(Redundant `values` is needed to generate the appropriate `GROUP BY`. See [aggregation topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) in Django documentation).