# How to reorganize data in a django view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following model for a Measurement belonging to a user:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='measurements')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)

    def get_date(self):
        return self.timestamp.date()
```

And for one of my views I need the measurements grouped by day. I have done the following:

```
def group_measurements_by_days(user_id):
    measurements = Measurement.objects.filter(user=user_id)
    daysd = {}
    for measurement in measurements:
        day = measurement.get_date()
        if not day in daysd:
            daysd[day] = []
        mymeas = daysd[day]
        mymeas.append(measurement)
    days = [{'day': day, 'measurements': measurements} for day, measurements in daysd.items()]
    days = sorted(days, key=itemgetter('day'), reverse=True)
    return days
```

So that I get a list like:

```
[
  { 'day': date1, 'measurements': [ Measurement, Measurement, ...]},
  { 'day': date2, 'measurements': [ Measurement, Measurement, ...]},  
  ...
]
```

But this is completely wrong, because I have a mixture of plain python types and django ORM types. This works when I use this data in templates, but is giving me trouble in other areas.

For example, when trying to reuse this code for a django rest api, I suddenly am unable to serialize those objects.

How can I process the data coming from the django ORM (`Measurement.objects.filter(user=user_id)`), but still keep a consistent format for my API?

Comment: If you need this to show it in a template, you could use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) built-in template tag from Django.

Comment: Why don't you wrap your for loop into a util function, then have an additional parameter to control the return value to be either your current data structure or plain python string that is serializable? Also you could make `daysd` a `defaultdict(list)` instead of `{}`, then you don't need those `if` statement anymore.

Comment: By the way, you can replace your `if` statement with something like this ...
`daysd.setdefault(day, []).append(measurement)`

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you are able to use Django 1.8. Problem solved in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872224/3925926) credits goes there.

You can filter the queryset using grouping by date:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Date

queryset = Measurements.objects.filter(user=user_id).annotate(day=Date('timestamp'), measurements=Count(0)).values('day', 'measurements')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382546/how-can-i-turn-django-model-objects-into-a-dictionary-and-still-have-their-forei) ...

```
    mymeas.append(measurement.__dict__)
```